# Is it possible to export the results of the ELevation Profile tool as a CSV file?

Tags: qgis, polyline

Very excited to learn about (and start using) the new Elevation Profile tool, as explained here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/elevation_profile.html.

Currently the results only seem to be presented as a graph within the Elevation Profile dialog.
Is it possible to export these results as a CSV file of XY pairs for loading into other software?

This was possible in the earlier Profile Tool (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/), but I don't see that option in the Elevation Profile tool. I am querying contour polylines, which are not compatible with the Profile tool.

Thanks.